# Knitr: siunitx clashes with OutDec = ","

Tags: math-mode, errors, siunitx, knitr

I'm having the following problem.

I'm trying to type up something in Danish, which means I want a comma for the decimal mark. Usually I have no issues doing this, I simply set

```
<<>>=
   options(OutDec = ",")
@
```

However, in my current document this introduced an error I was having trouble locating at first. Specifically, I'd get an error message of the form `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line [x]`. Playing around a bit, it seems the error arises from a clash with siunitx. Setting `OutDec = ","` appears to enclose numbers resulting from `\Sexpr{}` in `\text{}` while changing the decimal mark to a comma. Usually this isn't a problem, but \siunitx doesn't appear to like the combination of math mode and `\text{}`. At least, I get the relevant error message from the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    $ \SI{\text{1}}{\meter} $
\end{document}
```

However, I'd rather like to continue being able to use `\Sexpr{}` within `\SI{}{}` and get the correct decimal mark.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Why is knitr adding `\text` in the first place. Also, even though comma is the correct decimal in Danish, you are allowed to use dot as the decimal point as long as you are consistent. Otherwise you will have to write any decimal number either with `\SI` (if it has a unit)  or using `\num` if it s does not. This is very cumbersome, so often easiest to simply use dot for the decimal.

Comment: Not sure why knitr adds `\text`. And while I agree that using a dot is fine given consistency (I always do this myself), I've been specifically asked for this piece to follow the comma convention, so sadly this is not an option.

Comment: Did you try `\sisetupcpy-decimal-marker}` if your input uses a comma?

Comment: Even after some googling I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what this was meant to say (if it's a typo - otherwise I'm even more clueless). I have tried `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the following to get the correct decimal mark:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{document}
$\SI{1.5}{\meter}$
$\SI{1,5}{\meter}$ % ',' works, too
\end{document}
```

Comment: Presumably because a lot of his doc is being generated by knitr (the orig doc being a mixture of R and LaTeX)

Comment: That's a perfectly good solution for a standard latex. My problem arises, though, when I try to pass the numerical value of `x` in `\SI{x}{}` via \Sexpr{} using knitr. For this, I'm not sure this helps.

Comment: The answer is correct for a .Rnw file too. There are not problem to change in this example `1.5` by `\Sexpr{a}` where for instance  `a <- 4.3` (with dot). This will print `4,3` with comma and without error. As demonstrated just the MWE of the question,  the problem is not related in any form with R but with  the use of  `\text{}` inside the first argument of `\SI`, that  have not sense.